# What's the difference between homebrew python and caskroom python?

Tags: python, homebrew, homebrew-cask

The page [Installing Python on Mac OS X](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/) suggests that the OS X version is OK for learning but not great for writing real programs; solution - install from Homebrew.

I don't think the caskroom existed when they wrote this page though. Basically, I just want to install the most optimal version for doing Python programming.

When I do a search I get this output:

```
$ brew search python
boost-python   gst-python     python         python3        wxpython       zpython
Caskroom/cask/mod_python      homebrew/python/vpython           Caskroom/cask/python
homebrew/python/python-dbus   homebrew/versions/gst-python010   Caskroom/cask/python3
```

This is what homebrew reports:

```
macosx-10-9:~ vagrant$ brew cask info python
python: 2.7.9
Python
https://www.python.org/
Not installed
https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/python.rb
==> Contents
  python-2.7.9-macosx10.6.pkg (pkg)

macosx-10-9:~ vagrant$ brew info python
python: stable 2.7.10 (bottled), HEAD
Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
https://www.python.org
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2 (4906 files, 77M) *
  Poured from bottle
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/python.rb
```

So, what's the effective difference between these two packages?

Comment: From  http://lapwinglabs.com/blog/hacker-guide-to-setting-up-your-mac "Homebrew Cask is an extension for Homebrew that allows you to automate the installation of Mac Apps and Fonts".  I recommend using Continuum's Anaconda distribution on OS X, Linux and Mac, see http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install.

Answer (score 8):

Caskroom python installs the Python Mac OS X packages from https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/ as they are provided there.

`brew install python` will install from source and under `/usr/local/Cellar/python/...` and properly symlink `/usr/local/bin/python`.

The latter is the "proper homebrew approach" (TM) and will allow updates with `brew upgrade`.